Issues with my player and enemy not being drawn on to the canvas, any ideas?
This is the only issue im having currently with my scripts, im not sure if its the drawing order but ive tried to rearrange my drawing. If y'all can help me so that I can fix this issue that would be greatly appreciated .

function gameloop() {
  // Clear the canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // Draw background elements
// Set timeout to hide symbols after 5 seconds
  bg.draw();
  cloudBig.update(ctx);
  cloudBig2.update(ctx);

  backgroundLevel1.draw();

  water.draw();
  waterSmall.draw();
  waterSmallTwo.draw();
  palmTree.draw();
  palmTree2.draw();
  palmTreeSide.draw();
  palmTreeSide2.draw();

  // Draw the p1Symbol

  playerUpdate();
  p1Symbol.draw(); // Update game objects
  p1Symbolp.draw(); // Update game objects

  // p1update();
  // p1pupdate();
  p2Symbol.draw(); // Update game objects
  p2Symbolp.draw(); // Update game objects

  




  enemy.enemyMovement();
  player.movement();

  // Update hurtboxes
  player.updateHurtbox();
  enemy.updateHurtbox();

  // Draw game objects
  player.update();
  player.draw();
  enemy.update();
  enemy.draw();

  // Check collisions
  attackCollision();
  enemyAttackCollision();
  // CollisionBlocks.forEach(block => {
  //   block.draw();
  // });

  // Request the next frame
  window.requestAnimationFrame(gameloop);
}

// Start the game loop
gameloop();

I mentioned that ive tried rearranging my drawings. So not sure what's causing this issue.

We don't have enough information here to help you solve your problem. Can you give us some more context?

Looks like I just me a resource function to load all images before the gameloop starts. And that solved it

made a resource class to load in all files before the game loop.
